# Survival analysis on plant population data over time

Tags: survival, biostatistics

I am a researcher at Kew Gardens looking to analyse survival data on populations of reintroduced Green Winged Orchids to sites in Cumbria. I want to statistically analyse the different survivals of total orchid numbers in each of the 4 different sites. I am new to R and I do not know how to format the data for analysis and/or how to perform the analysis.

There are 4 different sites that we reintroduced plants back into, Gaitbarrows, Humphrey head, Jack Scout and the Lots. Within these 4 sites are subsites where the orchids were planted. The first date (October 15th) shows the initial numbers of plants reintroduced to these subsites, subsequent dates are the numbers of orchids in these same subsites.

[image: Table in R showing the raw data]

If any help could be provided that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post the data directly into the question? If you paste it in, select it, and use the `{}` code tool it will be formatted properly with 4 leading spaces so it's interpreted as code/values. It's very hard to read the image you posted, and those who use text-to-speech won't be able to "see" the data at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the R package `survival` (I refer to this package, considering you already have the data imported on R). The link is: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html

Now, the statistical test you may use will depend on the questions, and thus, the variables you will want to check. If you want to compare the four sites only, you can perform a Log-Rank test; however, if you want to compare further variables (like environmental data), you may want to look into Cox Regressions.
Furthermore, you might need to perform Cox Mixed Effects regressions (using the R package `coxme` - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/index.html) if you want to use a split-plot design based on the subsites you talk about in your description.

Both packages refered here have very good vignettes, that allows for understanding both the code and the theory behind it.